# EF 6 Code First not create database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, database-connection, connection-string, code-first

I searched many solutions but I can't understand why database does not create? My classes and context class are very simple.

```
public class News
{
    [Key]
    public int NewsID { get; set; }
    public string NewsHeader { get; set; }
    public string News { get; set; }

    public int CategoryID;
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

public class Category 
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName{ get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<News> Newss { get; set; }
}

public class NewsContext: DbContext
{
     public NewsContext(): base("NewsContext") 
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<NewsContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<NewsContext>());
    }
    public DbSet<News> Newss { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

and my connection string is right below

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="NewsContext" connectionString="Data Source=nevra\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=NewsContext;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Are you using automatic or manual migrations? Are you sure the database doesn't actually exist?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I am using automatic migrations and I have no error. Surely database cannot create, dont undertstand which step I missed.